# Sort by dates and value R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I have this dataframe:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(100, 300, NA, 430, 270)
c <- c('2018-02-01', '2020-02-17', '2019-10-24', '2019-10-24', '2020-02-17')
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
names(df) <- c('id', "value", "Date")
```

All I want is to sort the value of `Date`and `value` in the descending order. However I find that Date can be order by using `rev` but with NA the order is not correct :

```
df[rev(order(df$Date, df$value)),] ##
```

The result that I want should be like this:

```
  id value       Date
2  2   300 2020-02-17
5  5   270 2020-02-17
4  4   430 2019-10-24
3  3    NA 2019-10-24
1  1   100 2018-02-01
```

Any suggest to deal with NA in this dataframe without dropping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `na.last = FALSE` should do the trick:

```
df[rev(order(df$Date, df$value, na.last = FALSE)),]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try `dplyr` functions, since `arrange()` sorts `NA` values to last by default:

```
df %>%
  arrange(desc(Date),desc(value))
```

gives:

```
  id value       Date
1  2   300 2020-02-17
2  5   270 2020-02-17
3  4   430 2019-10-24
4  3    NA 2019-10-24
5  1   100 2018-02-01
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use data.table package, you can do it like this:

```
library(data.table)
setorderv(df, cols = c("Date","value"), order = -1, na.last=TRUE)
```